# Computing homology groups with GAP

Tags: gr.group-theory, computer-algebra, computational-group-theory, gap, group-homology

I’m studying the homology groups of arithmetic groups such as $SL(5,\mathbb{Z})$. I saw in the answer to [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/92567/program-for-computing-group-cohomology) post that we can use GAP to compute some of the homology groups for $SL(3,\mathbb{Z})$. Is the same true for $SL(5,\mathbb{Z})$? If so, how many homology groups can it compute?

In general, is there a database of some kind that has stored these types of homology calculations?

I apologize if these questions are naive. I’m very new to GAP and what it’s capabilities are.

Comment: I imagine what you can compute will largely be dictated by how  much system memory GAP can address and how long you can wait.  Why don't you try?

Comment: I figured this would be the case. I don’t currently have a device that can support it. Otherwise, I would look into this myself.

Comment: One needs to run "LoadPackage("HAP");;" before Graham's code.  Then it will compute the homology of SL(5,Z).

Answer (score 4):

Graham Ellis would be able to better comment on the correctness of his code for $SL(5,\mathbb Z)$, as he appears to be the author of the HAP package in GAP.

But his code executes quickly and claims to compute the homology of $SL(5,\mathbb Z)$.

$$H_2(SL_5(\mathbb Z), \mathbb Z)$$

```
LoadPackage("HAP");;
R:=ResolutionArithmeticGroup("SL(5,Z)",4);;
Homology(TensorWithIntegers(R),2);
```

Returns $[2, 12]$, which I believe means the code is claiming this homology $H_2$ group is isomorphic to $\mathbb Z_2 \oplus \mathbb Z_{12}$.  It similarly computes $H_3$ to be $\mathbb Z_2 \oplus \mathbb Z_{24}$, and $H_4$ to $\mathbb Z_{12}$.

I believe the 4 in the call for the resolution is a reference to the length of the resolution, so 4 is longer than required for $H_2$.  With the resolution of length 4 call, the code chokes on an $H_5$ computation.

As was pointed out in the comments these answers disagree with what's known in the literature.  After digging around in Graham Ellis's documentation a little more I found the comment regarding the ResolutionArithmeticGroup command:

```
Inputs a positive integer n
 and a string P
 equal to one of the following:

"SL(2,Z)" , "SL(3,Z)" , "PGL(3,Z[i])" ,  PGL(3,Eisenstein_Integers)" , "PSL(4,Z)" , "PSL(4,Z)_b" ,"PSL(4,Z)_c" , "PSL(4,Z)_d" , "Sp(4,Z)"
```

**So it would appear the answer to the question of this thread is no, GAP currently can't compute group homology of $SL_5(\mathbb Z)$.**

The documentation is here: https://docs.gap-system.org/pkg/hap/doc/chap0_mj.html

Click on Chapter 5 to find the above.

It's computing something, just not the homology of the group.

Comment: Thanks you for the response! It is strange to me that it computes $H_2(SL(5,\mathbb{Z})$ to be $\mathbb{Z}_2\times \mathbb{Z}_{12}$. The reference given in the answer here has it as $\mathbb{Z}_2$.

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/64551/cohomology-of-lattice-subgroups

Comment: Indeed, note that running your code actually produces an error (until one sets $R$ to be a resolution of some implemented group; and then runs the code again. Here, the package should return an error, but this is not done).

Comment: For example, once one has defined some implemented $R$ (e.g. by running "R:=ResolutionArithmeticGroup("SL(2,Z)",2);") then it never objects. For example, we can compute your homology groups by setting "R:=ResolutionArithmeticGroup("ryanbudney",2);", and no error is produced... :-) This is why reading the documentation is always important!

Comment: @Carl-FredrikNybergBrodda: no, the code produces the output I included, no error.  The error only happens if you forget to include the HAP library.

Comment: @RyanBudney I am running GAP4.12.2 on Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS and get an error ("No method found...") every time copying your code verbatim, and HAP (version 1.47) is certainly loaded. Perhaps the issue is somewhere deeper, then.

Comment: @Carl-FredrikNybergBrodda interesting.  I will send a link for this thread to Graham.  I imagine he will want to know.   I'm also running Ubuntu, but version 23.10, with GAP 4.12.1.

Comment: @RyanBudney I imagined so too -- I already wrote to Graham! It is strange, but in any case the conclusion seems to be that no method exists implemented in GAP for computing the homology of $\operatorname{SL}_5(\mathbb{Z})$. It would be interesting if one could be implemented, even if not a practical one...

Comment: HAP can not compute homology of SL(5,Z).  The code should say that data for this group is currently unavailable and then list the groups for which it is currently available. It certainly used to do this for such a group, but I must have introduced a bug at some stage. I'll look into it and fix it.  GAP needs the finite cell structure of a fundamental domain for a group action plus a list of cell stabilizers. I think that Philippe Elbaz-Vincent and others have this data for SL(5,Z) so it should not be difficult for me to include it. I'll look into this too.  Apologies for the confusion caused!

Comment: Thank you all for the time put into this! @GrahamEllis That would be fantastic if you could include the $SL(5,\mathbb{Z})$ case. Are you thinking of this paper: https://maths.dur.ac.uk/users/herbert.gangl/EGS.pdf

Comment: @Noah B  Yes that's the paper I had in mind. I've sent an email asking if I can have a copy of their fundamental domains.